# Can a constructor function be a friend in c++?

Tags: c++

Can we declare constructor of a class to be friend? I think it cannot be. But i read somewhere that it can be, but i was unable to do. If yes can you please provide some example code.

Comment: Why don't you declare the whole class a friend instead?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: That's useful in general, but what would you show here? `friend <what goes here> ;` ? That doesn't add anything to this question.

Comment: @MSalters: ??. sure it does. It should work, so there must be a specific syntactic problem in the OP's code, or maybe a misunderstanding regarding how friendliness works. either way, you could reflect to the actual problem, and not just say "it should work".

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Well, usually you'd write `friend <name-of-function>;`  but constructors don't have names so I can see a reasonable source of confusion.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes it can:

```
class Y
{
public:
     Y();
};
class X
{
private:
     void foo() {}  
     friend Y::Y();
};
Y::Y() 
{
   X x; x.foo(); 
}
```

As per **11.3 Friends [class.friend]**

> 5) When a friend declaration refers to an overloaded name or operator, only the function specified by the parameter types becomes a friend. **A
>   member function of a class X can be a friend of a class Y.**
>
> [ Example:

```
class Y {
friend char* X::foo(int);
friend X::X(char); // constructors can be friends
friend X::~X(); // destructors can be friends
};
```

> —end example ]

(emphasis mine)

Comment: is this valid
`class Y
{
   public:
      friend Y(int);
}`
If yes how would you define Y(int);

Comment: @Shreyas that wouldn't make sense, why would a class (or member) be a friend of itself?

Comment: `class Y { friend class Y; };` is valid but redundant. Same goes for `class Y { Y(int); friend Y::Y(int); };`