# How am I supposed to make my allocator rebindable? Can I do it while keeping its fields private?

Tags: c++, templates, friend, allocator

Long story short, here's the problem:

```
template<class T>
struct alloc
{
    template<class U>
    alloc(alloc<U> const &other) : foo(other.foo) { }  // ERROR: other.foo is private 
    template<class U> struct rebind { typedef alloc<U> other; };
private:
    pool<T> *foo;  // do I HAVE to expose this?
};
```

Is the only solution to expose the private fields publicly?
How are you supposed to actually to make the conversion constructor?

Comment: It's should be possible, by making the constructor a `friend`, but I can't figure out the syntax :/

Comment: @Rakete1111: I assume you mean make the class a friend? I don't think you can refer to constructors in any way at all, let alone try to make them your friend.

Comment: [But constructors can be friends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310297/can-a-constructor-function-be-a-friend-in-c) :) Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Rakete1111: Huh, I thought that was illegal, my bad!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the template copy constructor, `alloc<T>` and `alloc<U>` are different type, means you can't access the private member of `alloc<U>` here.

You can make `alloc<U>` friend:

```
template<class T>
struct alloc
{
    ... ...
    template <typename U>
    friend struct alloc;
    alloc(alloc<U> const &other) : foo(other.foo) {} // possible to access other.foo now
};
```

Comment: For some reason I thought declaring a template as a friend would be illegal. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

My own guess is that this is not possible, and that you're supposed to use a conversion operator:

```
template<class U>
operator alloc<U>() const { return alloc<U>(this->foo); }
```

but I'm hoping there's a better answer...