# Making the constructors/assignment operators of a typedef friend functions

Tags: c++, templates

I've been working on a templated type that should only be copy/move constructible/assignable within another specific type's own assignment/construction. (in an attempt to prevent subtle errors in user-facing code)

This other type is a typedef within the template parameter, so to save typing I use another typedef within the class definition. Relevant implementation bits:

```
template<typename Info>
class Foo {
  using T = typename Info::some_t;
  Foo(const Foo&) = default;
  Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = default;
  // ...
public:
  Foo() = default;
  // ...
};
```

I can't use a blanket `friend class T;` statement since I don't want T at large to have access. As an alternative, making the relevant assignment operators and constructors friends seems plausible. I believe you can make the constructors of another type friends via `friend X::X(...);` and I've assumed that `friend X::operator=(...);` is also valid. However, trying to write `friend T::T(const T&);` within Foo triggers compiler errors. I tried it with the other constructor types and assignment operators as well unsuccessfully.

MSVC warns that 'T': dependent name is not a type and errors on identifier T in the parameters. It suggests putting `typename` before T, which removes the warning but still errors on T within the parameter list. (albeit with a slightly different message) Is there a valid syntax for doing this? Alternatively, is there another way to enforce the restrictions I'm aiming for?

Comment: You can believe in having a friend constructor all you want, but compilers will have none of it.  Who's right?

Comment: I will add that `using T = typename Info::some_t;` does not grant any rights to Info::some_t into your class, over which you have full control.

Comment: What is the *problem* you're trying to solve (XY-problem)?

Comment: A problem with making the constructor a friend is that the constructor is special and doesn't really have a name. When you use `Foo()` to construct an object, that is the class name you are using.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy I can't claim to have independently verified it, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310297/can-a-constructor-function-be-a-friend-in-c) it should be possible.

Comment: The actual use-case is C# style properties, but I didn't want to get into the actual semantics of the type. The short version is that it's specialized per property per class, and internally it only updates its reference to the parent on construction, and does nothing on assignment. The problem is that the assignment operator is a nop, and that may not be obvious to an end user doing a.transform.position = b.transform.position.

Comment: And as for the other point, I'm just making the distinction between `friend class T;` and these individual friend function declarations. I'll update that so it's clearer in the post.

Comment: I have verified it personally several times in the last 30 years.  A friend function is NOT a member of a class, so cannot be one of its constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot declare a constructor using a typedef-name. The standard explicitly prohibits this in [class.ctor]/1:

> The *class-name* shall not be a *typedef-name*.

If you use a typedef-name that coincides with the (inner) class-name, you can kind of work around this:

```
using some_t = typename Info::some_t;
```

Comment: Ah, that explains it. The work around seems to trigger the same errors, but thanks for the info!

Comment: Maybe depends on the compiler. The letter of the standard says it shouln't work but I don't think that's the intent.